# Unable to connect to opendistro elasticsearch using metricbeat

Tags: macos, docker, metricbeat, elasticsearch-opendistro

Somehow i could manage to run the opendistro cluster on my local mac using docker with kibana dashboard and elasticsearch APIs working as expected. But getting the following error while communicating to elasticsearch from metricbeat.
*"Failed to connect to backoff(elasticsearch(https://localhost:9200)): Get https://localhost:9200: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"*

Is there any way to call elasticsearch with insecure flag from metricbeat?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found a solution. Just add the below line in your metricbeat.yaml file under elasticsearch.output

ssl.verification_mode: none